# Getting opposed order as result

Tags: jquery, arrays, click, each

Check this code out:

```
var test = new Array();

//I need each() to get the data from every row
$(".quiz_list_row").each(function(index){

    // Gets the data necessary from HTML5 tag data
    $quiz_list_id = $(this).data("quizlistId");
    $quiz_level_reached = $(this).data("quizlevelReached");

    test [0] = new Array($quiz_list_id,$quiz_level_reached);

    $(this).click(function(){
    alert("test: "+test.toString());
    });
)};
```

The divs are like this (it's correct):

```
<div class="quiz_list_row" data-quizlist-id="1" data-quizlevel-reached="5">
     <div class="inline" id="quiz_list_cell_id1">Quiz 1</div>
     <div class="inline" id="quiz_list_cell_id2">Current level: 5</div>
</div>
<div class="quiz_list_row" data-quizlist-id="2" data-quizlevel-reached="7">
     <div class="inline" id="quiz_list_cell_id1">Quiz 2</div>
     <div class="inline" id="quiz_list_cell_id2">Current level: 7</div>
</div>
```

So when I click on the first div, which was supposed to show "1,5" on the first alert and "2,7" on the second one, I get the opposite.

Comment: I see the overwriting "test" ' I have to fix that =)

Comment: Ignoring the syntax errors, it should show "2,7" when clicking anywhere. The same `test[0]` array is overwritten on each iteration of the loop.

Comment: I don't think it causes this problem, but HTML IDs must be *unique*. Currently, you have two elements with ID `quiz_list_cell_id1` and two with `quiz_list_cell_id2`. This is invalid HTML and may give you headaches later on.

Comment: You are not getting the opposite order.. you are always getting 2,7. Please explain what you are trying to achieve..

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli I know it looks weird, but I am actually getting 1,5 after the first click!

Comment: @MattiasBuelens Thank you for you advice! I'll change the ids to "quiz_list_cell_row1_id1"

Comment: @Juhana Do you see any syntax error? Please let me know.. the ");" missing after alert was just a misspelling while typing the question here. As I told Gaby, I'm rly getting 1,5 after the first click. It's weird but I am!

Comment: @Th3B0Y The last line should be `});`. Why are you typing in the code? Copy-paste it exactly as it is. You can't expect people to be able to help if you don't show the *exact* code you have -- the one you typed here *will* alert 2,7: see http://jsfiddle.net/gjjKx/

Comment: @Juhana I did that! The problem is solved now =) Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the changes I made:

```
var test = new Array();

$(".quiz_list_row").each(function(index){
        // Gets the data necessary to show game chosen
        $quiz_list_id = $(this).data("quizlistId");
        $quiz_level_reached = $(this).data("quizlevelReached");

            test.push($quiz_list_id,$quiz_level_reached);

        $(this).click(function(){
            alert("test: "+test);
        });

});
```

The divs:

```
<div class="quiz_list_row" data-quizlist-id="1" data-quizlevel-reached="5">
    <div class="inline quiz_list_cell" id="quiz_list_cell_row0_id1">Quiz 1</div>
    <div class="inline quiz_list_cell" id="quiz_list_cell_row0_id2">Current level: 5</div>
</div>
<div class="quiz_list_row" data-quizlist-id="2" data-quizlevel-reached="7">
    <div class="inline quiz_list_cell" id="quiz_list_cell_row1_id1">Quiz 2</div>
    <div class="inline quiz_list_cell" id="quiz_list_cell_row1_id2">Current level: 7</div>
</div>
```

The credits are on the comments, ok?

Answer (score 0):

You are over writing `test[0]` on every pass of the loop

Try replacing `test[0]=` with:

```
test.push([$quiz_list_id,$quiz_level_reached])
```